# external asterisk registration is unreacheable

Tags: networking, asterisk

I've searched the web for a week now and I've found nothing to resolve the issue.

I have an external Asterisk in the cloud.

I configured SIP in a softphone in my office which is behind a firewall(**pfsense**).

The softphone has successfully logged in. But the status in Asterisk is SIP unreacheable.

I tried to dial the softphone but it was unreacheable also.

Please need your expertise regarding this matter.

Comment: you need to tell us more about your setup. how do you connect to the cloud? how is the firewall set up? do you use NAT? is the NAT done by pfsense? do you use STUN?

Answer (score 0):

If Asterisk show that your softphone is unreachable then you have to check the path from your softphone to the Asterisk to find where the SIP packets are getting lost.

Check these points:

1- In `sip.conf` verify that the line with **externip** contains the external IP address your Asterisk is using.

2- In `sip.conf`there should be a section for your softphone. Something like this for extension 3030:

```
[3030]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=mysecret 
dtmfmode=inband
canreinvite=yes
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=no
type=friend
nat=no
port=5060
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
transport=udp,tcp,tls
dial=SIP/3030
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

Verify that the secret is the same as the password configured in the softphone.

3- If the firewall is using **NAT** then in the previous configuration you have to enable *nat* and verify in Asterisk the parameters in the file `sip_nat.conf`.

4- The asterisk log will give more information about the SIP negotiation between the softphone and Asterisk. A succesful login look like this:

```
[2016-08-16 11:12:21] NOTICE[4124]: chan_sip.c:23707 handle_response_peerpoke: Peer '3030' is now Reachable. (1ms / 2000ms)
```

Please, update your question with information about which softphone you're using and the version of Asterisk you have.

Comment: when i log-in outside the office network the sip is reacheable. Also if i login in our office the sip IP appeared  in asterisk(sip show peers) is my local IP and not my WAN IP. Since it sees my local ip not my public IP thats may be the reason its unreacheable coz my asterisk cannot find the said local IP. But i cannot point where to fix this.

Comment: Try the options in point 2 with `sip=yes`, `sip=force_rport`, `sip=comedia` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098086/asterisk-sip-parse-nat-option-nat-yes-is-deprecated-use-nat-force-rport-come) and check the parameters also in your softphone.

Comment: i use eyebeam to both office and myhome. Both are on the same setup. In my home the sip registered and the status is reacheable while in my office the sip registered but the status is unreacheable in sip show peers. Both of them use the same SIP.

Comment: here is my sip_additional.conf  [100]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=secret
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=yes
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
mediaencryption=no
sendrpid=no
type=friend
nat=no
port=5060
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
transport=udp
avpf=no
force_avp=no
icesupport=no
encryption=no
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
dial=SIP/100
mailbox=100@default
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callerid=100 <100>
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
cc_monitor_policy=generic

Comment: From you last message I see that you are using FreePBX. In the web interface of FreePBX enable NAT for the extension.